# RecyclerView Items Overlap After Animation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView setup and I have been having a very weird issue where during certain adapter update, items of the RecyclerView overlap each other as if they stop animation in the middle of their animation. This issue seems to primarily occur when items are moved but sometimes removing has the same effect. My initial setup was using the `AndroidX` beta01 `ListAdapter` along with Room for my app database. I would simply observe the `LiveData` and inside the observe method I would call `submitList()`

I should also note that I added a RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver which extended `onItemMoved` and called `layoutManager.moveToPosition(0)` to make sure the user saw the update.

Since then I have tried a number of troubleshooting steps, these include:

- Getting rid of stable IDs
- Writing my own logic for the adapter diff (I extended RecyclerView.Adapter) and would manually find the list diffs using the code below:
- I commented out the `moveToPosition(0)` code
- I overrode all of the methods inside the AdapterDataObserver to make sure the correct actions were taking place; they were

Manual List Diff Method:

```
private fun calculateListDiffs(model: List<T>) {
        when {
            model.size > list.size -> {
                var i = 0

                while (i < itemCount) {
                    if (!areItemsSame(list[i], model[i])) {
                        list.add(i, model[i])
                        notifyItemInserted(i)
                    } else
                        i++
                }
            }
            model.size < list.size -> {
                var i = 0

                while (i < itemCount) {
                    when {
                        i >= model.size && !areItemsSame(list[i], model[model.size - 1]) -> {
                            list.removeAt(i)
                            notifyItemRemoved(i)
                        }
                        i < model.size && !areItemsSame(list[i], model[i]) -> {
                            list.removeAt(i)
                            notifyItemRemoved(i)
                        }
                        else -> i++
                    }
                }
            }
            else -> {
                run loop@{
                    for (i in 0 until itemCount) {
                        when {
                            !areItemsSame(list[i], model[i]) -> {
                                val pivot = model[i]

                                for (j in i until itemCount) {
                                    if (areItemsSame(list[j], pivot)) {
                                        list.removeAt(j)
                                        list.add(i, pivot)
                                        notifyItemMoved(j, i)
                                        notifyItemChanged(i)
                                        return@loop
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            !areContentsSame(list[i], model[i]) -> {
                                list[i] = model[i]
                                notifyItemChanged(i)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue still persists and after all this testing it seems that it is an issue inherent to the adapter's animations and not the ListAdapter or my own diff method.

**Edit:** It should be noted that due to the way my app works, items in the inbox need to be moved to a new position as well as updated. So maybe there is some issue with calling `notifyItemMoved` and `notifyItemChanged`

Answer (score 3):

Come to find out, weirdly enough, it was an issue with a shared element transition. Apparently the transition somehow caused the recyclerview to not animate correctly, after removing the shared element everything functions as it is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

It also happens to me. Thanks for sharing the cause. I get rid of it by submitting the list after the shared element reenter transition ends which causes the animation of recycler view to happen after the transition.

```
    var transitionReenterFlag = false

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        requireActivity().window.sharedElementReenterTransition.doOnStart { transitionReenterFlag = true }
     ...
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
                    //first let the transition happen then submit the list
                    //to postpone the animation of recyclerview
                    if(transitionReenterFlag) {
                        requireActivity().window.sharedElementReenterTransition.addListener(object : Transition.TransitionListener{
                            override fun onTransitionStart(transition: Transition?) {}

                            override fun onTransitionEnd(transition: Transition?) {
                                transitionReenterFlag = false
                                adapter.submitList(list)
                                //happen only for one time when something is changed in the db
                                requireActivity().window.sharedElementReenterTransition
                                    .removeListener(this)
                            }

                            override fun onTransitionCancel(transition: Transition?) {}

                            override fun onTransitionPause(transition: Transition?) {}

                            override fun onTransitionResume(transition: Transition?) {}

                        })
                    }
                    else adapter.submitList(list)

    }
```

I am using recycler view inside my fragment. You can also do it in the activity.